# Is it possible to route all traffic from and to my local PC through an AWS instance using port forwarding?

Tags: networking, ssh, putty

I am trying to make use of PuTTY's port forwarding abilities to establish a connection from my home PC (running on Windows 11) to an AWS Lightsail instance (running on Ubuntu LTS 20.04) that I've provisioned and setup. The idea is to use the internet connectivity, available to the instance, via my home PC- kind of like using a proxy server or VPN to access the internet.

Assume the following parameters:

- Public IP address of the AWS instance: `x.x.x.x`
- Private IP address of the AWS instance: `Y.Y.Y.Y`
- SSH port: `22`
- I have opened up port `6088` at both the account level and instance level
- Public IP address of my local pc(router IP): `a.a.a.a`
- Private IP address of my local pc: `b.b.b.b`

My theoretical understanding so far is that I should use PuTTY for remote port forwarding the remote Lightsail instance's port 6088 to my home PCs corresponding local port at 6088.

I have been trying (unsuccessfully) to access the remote internet from my PC after configuring the home pc's proxy settings to `localhost:6088`. I had initially planned on accessing the remote instance via a VNC client-server scheme but could not get it to work either.

After Googling around a bit, I've come to know that AWS also offers instances specifically for purposes of setting up VPN networks and that these enable the kind of use case I am considering.

Can anyone suggest what the correct way is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have the forwarding mode backwards. "Remote" forwarding causes the server to be the listener; connections would be made to the server address:port (maybe at localhost:6088 from within the server, or maybe at serverip:6088 from other hosts) and forwarded to your client system.

   What you're trying to do is the complete opposite of that, so it would involve something more like the "Local" forwarding mode, where the SSH *client* is the listener for port 6088 (and the AWS server's firewall rules are irrelevant).
2. Both "Remote" and "Local" modes are fixed-function; that is, they don't allow the app to specify where it wants to connect – they always forward to the specified destination only. For example, if you have a "Local" forward where the local port is 6088 and the remote destination is google.com:443, then *every* connection to localhost:6088 will be relayed to google.com:443 and nowhere else.

   (This also means that even if "Local" or "Remote" *was* the suitable mode, you wouldn't use the port in *proxy* configuration – you'd use it directly as if it were the actual service.)

   Instead you need the third mode in PuTTY – "Dynamic" forwarding – which is still in the same category as "Local", but it makes PuTTY act like a SOCKS proxy. With a "Dynamic" forward on port 6088, you can configure your browser to use localhost:6088 as the SOCKS proxy and be able to browse through the AWS server.
3. PuTTY can only act as a SOCKS proxy, and Firefox and Chrome know how to use proxies that speak SOCKS, but many other apps don't; it's relatively common to see apps that support "HTTP CONNECT" but not SOCKS.

   Since PuTTY doesn't have a function to emulate that, you might need to run a *real* HTTP proxy server (e.g. Squid or Privoxy) on the AWS server, then use "Local" forwarding to access it via SSH. (Or maybe do what Tor does/used to do, and run Privoxy/Polipo locally and point it at PuTTY's "Dynamic" port, going 'browser→HTTP→Privoxy→SOCKS→PuTTY→SSH→AWS'.)
4. All of the above can only handle TCP traffic; if you need UDP for anything (or even if you want `ping` to be proxied), neither of those proxy types will work.

   In that case you will need to set up a whole VPN tunnel between your PC and the AWS server. (SSH can't do that on Windows and is not very suitable for it in general; instead you'd use OpenVPN or Tailscale or WireGuard or something similar.) You don't need a special kind of server for that purpose.

   (There are server types that aren't suitable for setting up a VPN, namely the extremely cheap "VPSes" offered by some providers that are just OpenVZ containers in disguise, although even those can typically host at least OpenVPN. I don't think AWS has anything like that; all their VPSes are fully functioning virtual servers.)